# Setting an APC SU700I UPS for PC hibernation after 2min of power outage? (APC UPS experienced user might be needed)

Tags: hibernate, ups, apc-powerchute

I have an APC SU700I UPS connected to my PC via a serial cable. I'm running Windows 7 x64, and Vmware Workstation on this PC. I'm using APC PowerChute Business Edition v8.0 web agent interface.

The problems are:

1. One day, when I came home, I found that the PC was shut down forced (I'm guessing that the battery drained completely) and the UPS was turned off. I discovered that there was a 2 hour power outage.
   One of the reasons that I'm suspecting for this hibernation failure is that I left the PC locked (one of the options from the start menu: shut down, restart, hibernate, log out, switch user, lock). What do you think? Could this be a problem?
2. I have another issue with the UPS. Let's say I'm at the PC and I have a power outage for 30 sec. I decide to put my PC to hibernation manually. The PC has hibernated. The power comes back, I turn on the PC, but in ~30mins, the UPS turns itself off, no warning whatsoever, cutting the power from the PC, too.
   This is a major no-no.

What I want:
I want the UPS to hibernate the PC after 2mins of power outage, and then it should do nothing. No power off by itself, nothing.

Comment: `s/experimented/experienced/`?

Comment: My mistake. I saw it after I posted, but I can't edit it, because Olli added the embedded picture.  :">